# How to reindex one record by thinking-sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I didn't use delta, or delayed, or datetime solution to  my modal. and I want to reindex a record when it's changed .  for example, my object is `business`, is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to fully update a single record in Sphinx when the indices are SQL-backed - you can only process one index at a time, hence why delta solutions take that approach with smaller delta indices alongside the larger core indices.

However, you could perhaps look into real-time indices instead, which Thinking Sphinx also supports. [This blog post](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/rewriting_thinking_sphinx_introducing_realtime_indices) is currently the best source of information.